# Is there a way to create organization folder in Jenkins for Bitbucket Server(Stash)

Tags: jenkins, directory, jenkins-pipeline, organization, bitbucket-server

I see we can create organization folder in Jenkins for Bitbucket or GitHub by setting up Bitbucket Teams for Bitbucket and GitHub Organization for GitHub. This helps to scan the repositories and get them into Jenkins(to organization folder) and automatically create Multibranch pipeline project

Is there a way to do the same for Bitbucket Server i.e., to create a Organization folder for it and scan for repos, get them to Organization folder and create Multibranch pipeline project automatically

Comment: https://github.com/jenkinsci/configuration-as-code-plugin/blob/master/demos/jobs/bitbucket.yaml

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by installing the plugin **BITBUCKET SERVER INTEGRATION**.
While creating the job, select Bitbucket Teams project.
Under **projects**,
The credentials are of Bitbucket Server(Stash)
Owner field is the project key of Project which is created in Bitbucket Server
Give Jenkinsfile in Pipeline Jenkinsfile field.

In Jenkins-> Configure system,

Under **Bitbucket Server integration**
Add instance details
Personal access token is generated in Bitbucket Server(latest versions)
Under **Bitbucket Server**
Add server URL details.

After running job,
we will find a **multibranch pipeline project** being created with the name of project which is in Bitbucket Server.